# Google Analytics: how to create a view which only has some events

Tags: google-analytics

We need to provide a customer with the data about some specific Google Analytics events produced by our mobile app, but we would like to hide all the other analytics data about the app.

Anyone can shed some light on how to do this in Google Analytics?

Comment: Does this need to work with data that's already collected ? For incoming data you could create a custom dimension that's only passed with the events and use that with an include filter.

Comment: It doesn't need to apply to data already collected, it's good enough for incoming data. Can you explain better how to create this custom dimension? Many thanks!

Comment: I take it by "mobile app" you mean android/iOs and I'm not very knowledable with mobile programming, but then the documentation on this looks rather comprehensive (Android documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets)

Comment: @EikePierstorff, yes it's for Android. I am actually already logging events:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events
And I would like to create a view, which only include some specific events. Does your solution only work for custom dimensions and not for standard events?

Answer (score 0):

Two choices: 1) you could just create a dashboard with just the data their eyes need to see / benefits them, 2) administration configurations can be set to only show certain views.  Views can be configured to show only one account, one property or even one subsection of a property

Comment: Thanks! with the Dashboard I was able to exactly compose the data I need to share, but I didn't find the way to share the data with other accounts which don't have access to the view.

Comment: on the other hand, how can you configure a view to only show a subsection of a property?

Comment: I have managed to include only the specific event by creating an include filter. Is there a way to remove the data of the other sections: e.g RealTime, Acquisition, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to configure access at the view level.  This has details on how exactly https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en

Comment: I can see I should set the permission to just Read&Analize, that gives access to all data. How can I hide data about RealTime or Acquisition?

Comment: Just go with dashboard or create a custom scheduled report or API

Comment: I can create dashboards inside the view, but all the vertical menu sections stay visible